# How do I secure my new web server (Server 2008)?

Tags: security

I've just put my new server up on an IP address with a domain pointing to it. I need to be able to remote admin it. I've opened the firewall for Remote Desktop and HTTP traffic. Is this going to be secure enough? I guess I should probably rename the administrator user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute minimum you should do is change the Remote Desktop port, change the Admin username, and have a very strong admin password.

Answer (score 4):

Should be sufficient, as long as you use a crazy-complex password for the admin account, and make sure your http server is security-patched and up-to-date.

Also, I hope firewall != Windows Firewall.

Edit: +1 for EHaskin's suggestion of changing RD port, if only to reduce the bruteforce spam that your FW will have to endure, but never think that security == obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can set up your server as a VPN endpoint?  Then you would only have the VPN ports and the HTTP ports open.  When you want to RDP to the server, you would connect to the VPN first and then you're good to go.

Only reason is, if my memory serves me right, RDP traffic is not encrypted.

This is how I run my IIS server at home, works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 supports VPN capabilities.  You can configure your remote access policies by using the Network Policy and Access Services.  I believe this needs to be installed as a role before you can use it.  Also, simply changing the RDP port on your firewall will not prevent an experienced hacker from still getting to your server.  A simple port scan would reveal open ports.